# Concurrency on NSMainQueueConcurrencyType and NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType contexts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency

Managed object context initialised with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType and  NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType ties to main queue and private queue which are serial queues where operations are executed in FIFO order.

With below sample code:

```
NSLog(@"Current thread : %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

[mainMoc performBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"main 1 - %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

}];

[mainMoc performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSLog(@"main 2 - %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

}];

[mainMoc performBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"main 3 - %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

}];

[bgMoc performBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"bg 1 - %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

}];

[bgMoc performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSLog(@"bg 2 - %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

}];

[bgMoc performBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"bg 3 - %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

}];
```

I was expecting it to print

`main 1`, `main 2` and `main 3` like `bg 1`, `bg 2` and `bg 3` in serial order but instead this was printed:

```
Current thread : <NSThread: 0x60000006fb80>{number = 1, name = main}
main 2 - <NSThread: 0x60000006fb80>{number = 1, name = main}
bg 1 - <NSThread: 0x600000268900>{number = 3, name = (null)}
bg 2 - <NSThread: 0x60000006fb80>{number = 1, name = main}
bg 3 - <NSThread: 0x600000268900>{number = 3, name = (null)}
main 1 - <NSThread: 0x60000006fb80>{number = 1, name = main}
main 3 - <NSThread: 0x60000006fb80>{number = 1, name = main}
```

What could be the theory behind it given both main and private queue are serial?

Answer (score 3):

Concurrency is non-deterministic. The only thing you're guaranteed is that "main1" is being executed before "main3", because it is, as you said, a FIFO queue.

It is important to differentiate between `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait`.

`performBlock` is asynchronous, so it just puts the block into the queue and returns immediately. Those blocks will be executed in order. Thats why "main1" will always be executed before "main3".

`performBlockAndWait` is synchronous and thus can't take care of the queue by definition. This means it will execute the block right now and it won't return until it's done. 
If it didn't do this, it would block, because the queue isn't empty or it would have to execute all the other tasks in the queue first.

Now the reason for why "bg1" comes before "bg2" is scheduling. I'm almost certain, that if you execute this test multiple times, it might eventually be different.
If the main-thread would be faster to reach the synchronous "bg2" it would appear first.

Comment: I believe the answer above to be not completely accurate when it comes to the reason for performBlockAndWait being executed immediately which leads to "main2" being logged before "main1". The actual reason is that performBlockAndWait for "main2" is called on the main queue and hence is executed directly on the main queue, while the performBlock calls are scheduled for execution. This is actually special behavior of performBlockAndWait: If it is called on the same queue as the queue associated with the context, it is executed immediately and not scheduled.